# CMFCPropertyGridProperty list of values?

Tags: list, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

Is there a standard way to hold a user editable list of values in a CMFCPropertyGridProperty?  I'm thinking a string with semi-colon delimiter (that seems to be the windows standard).  If I want an edit interface for this how would I build that?

Answer (score 3):

**One option**:

You can inherit `CMFCPropertyGridProperty` and override `HasButton`, returning `TRUE`. This will cause an ellipsis ("...") button to appear in the right-hand side of the value field. Override `OnClickButton` to provide your user interface for editing the list of values. You can pop up a dialog with a list control and a way to add/remove/edit items in the list. Override `FormatProperty` to display the list of values in the value field, and override `ResetOriginalValue` and implement code to restore the value you are constructed with.

**Another option**:

Inherit `CMFCPropertyGridProperty` and override `OnKillFocus`. If the user-entered value violates the formatting that you allow (semicolon-separated list of integers, for example), pop up a warning and return `FALSE` to prevent the edit from being committed.